# Поиск максимальной суммы квадратов чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, поиск

Требуется найти максимальную сумму квадратов двух натуральных чисел, которая будет близка(или равна) к заданному числу.

**Примеры:**

> 20 -> 20  т.к. (4<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup>)
>   50 -> 50  т.к. (5<sup>2</sup> + 5<sup>2</sup> или 7<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup>)
>   30 -> 29  т.к. (5<sup>2</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup>)

Не пойму, почему моя программа неверна.

```
res = int((N)**0.5)
res1 = int(((N-res**2)**0.5))
print(res**2+res1**2)
```

Comment: Ну хотя бы потому, что она в принципе неспособна найти все решения, если их несколько (например 25 = 5*5+0*0 = 3*3+4*4). И потому, что ни одно из чисел не обязано быть максимально близко к `sqrt(N)` (например, 89 = 8*8+5*5, а ты на первом же шаге получишь sqrt(89) = 9). И "максимально близка" - необязательно "меньше". В общем, логика неверна, точнее, просто отсутствует.

Comment: И обычно, "поиск макс., которая близка или равна..." таки означает <=

Comment: @vp_arth Ну тогда 50 = 5*5+5*5 = 7*7+1*1. Какая разница-то?

Comment: @Akina, можно предположить, что ответом для 50 будет 50 =)

Comment: @vp_arth Сам-то понял, что сказал? Для исходного 50 есть два ответа: (5;5) и (7;1). Что я собственно и показал.

Comment: @Akina, в вопросе выше не требуется находить сами квадраты, требуется найти ближайшее снизу число, которое разложимо на 2 квадрата. "найти ... **сумму** ..."

Comment: @vp_arth Предполагается всё-таки, что будет показано, что найденная сумма действительно представима в виде суммы квадратов двух натуральных, а не взята с потолка. Т.е. решение неявно требует указания этих самых двух натуральных. *требуется найти ближайшее снизу число* Ну ГДЕ??? где написано, что СНИЗУ??? Более того, если заданное число непредставимо в виде суммы двух квадратов, а числа на 1 больше и на 1 меньше представимы, то в соответствии с формулировкой задания предпочтительным является бОльшее - оно как бы максимальнее... Т.е. если задано 9, то правильный ответ 10 (3;1), а не 8 (2;2).

Comment: Ну вот же написано: "найти максимальную сумму, близкую или равную". Очевидно, что снизу) Иначе, если представимы и N, и N+1, придётся предпочесть N+1... Для 9, правильный ответ таки просто "8"

Comment: Ну и, теорема Эйлера таки добавляет 0 к ряду квадратов, так что её использование допустимо, только, если использовать 0. Тогда `9 -> 9`

Comment: @vp_arth что-то вы куда-то не в ту сторону пошли... Искать квадраты намного проще чем заниматься факторизацией.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, а вот с этим сложно не согласиться)

Comment: @user1337157 Запостил ответ который делает перебором, находит список всех возможных вариантов, при этом для 10^9 даёт ответ мгновенно, меньше 0.1 секунды.

Comment: @vp_arth: если представимы и `N` и `N+1`, то ответ `N` так как `N` ближе к `N` чем `N+1`. То есть формулировка в вопросе допускает в виде ответа первое представимое число из N, N+1, N-1, N+2,N-2. К примеру, для `30` ответ `29` (пифагорово простое `4*k+1`), так как `30` и `31` не представимы (они содержат простой гауссова множитель (`4*k+3`) в нечётной степени). Автору вопроса стоит явно уточнить, можно ли сумму больше заданного `N` рассматривать.

Comment: Нет, не стоит. Ответ <= N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваше решение неверное так как `int(N**.5)**2` не обязан быть одним из слагаемых в сумме. К примеру, 18 = 3<sup>2</sup> + 3<sup>2</sup>, а ваше решение возвращает 17 = 4<sup>2</sup> + 1<sup>2</sup> для N=18 (`17 < 18` поэтому это не является наибольшей суммой квадратов чисел близких к `N`).

Помимо перебора, можно построить решение на основе [теоремы о сумме двух квадратов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem), из которой следуют [разрешённые варианты разложения числа на простые множители](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.87.D1.91.D1.82_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.B2_.D0.B2.D0.B8.D0.B4.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.83.D0.BC.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D0.B4.D0.B2.D1.83.D1.85_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2) — целое число `m > 1` является суммой квадратов *тогда и только тогда* когда у него нет простых множителей вида `4*n+3` в нечётной степени:

```
def is_sum_of_two_squares(m):
    p = 2
    while m > 1:
        multiplicity = 0
        while m % p == 0:  # found prime factor
            multiplicity += 1
            m //= p
        if multiplicity & 1:  # odd power
            if p % 4 == 3:    # 4*n+3 form
                return False
        p += 1
    return True
```

Имея способ определить является ли натуральное число суммой квадратов, можно найти наибольшую сумму близкую к числу, перебирая рядом стоящие числа (от близких к далёким, от больших к маленьким числам):

```
def max_sum_of_two_squares_nearest(m):
    for i in range(m + 1):
        if is_sum_of_two_squares(m + i):
            return m + i
        elif is_sum_of_two_squares(m - i):
            return m - i
    assert 0
```

Пример:

```
for m in range(21):
    print(m, "->", max_sum_of_two_squares_nearest(m))
```

#### [Результат](https://ideone.com/asiOS1)

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 4
4 -> 4
5 -> 5
6 -> 5
7 -> 8
8 -> 8
9 -> 9
10 -> 10
11 -> 10
12 -> 13
13 -> 13
14 -> 13
15 -> 16
16 -> 16
17 -> 17
18 -> 18
19 -> 20
20 -> 20
```

Comment: элегантное решение!

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа неверна потому что она рассматривает только один случай. Так, 89 = 64 + 25 но ваша программа найдет только 85 = 81 + 4.

Вместо "жадного" выбора первого числа по формуле `int((N)**0.5)` правильнее будет перебрать все варианты от `0` до `int((N)**0.5)` и выбрать среди них наилучший. Формулу для второго числа можете оставить ту же самую.

Comment: А если простые числа не учитываются? Тоже все верно?

Comment: @user1337157 а зачем тут простые числа?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагая, что Вам таки не важно(могу ошибаться) в какие именно суммы разложимо число, предлагаю решение полным перебором до `sqrt(N)`:

```
from math import sqrt

x = int(input())

def check(x):
  sn = int(sqrt(x))+1
  for i in range(1, sn):
    j = int(sqrt(x - i*i))
    if (i*i+j*j == x):
      # print("{0}^2 + {1}^2".format(i, j))
      return True
  return False

while x > 0:
  if check(x):
      print(x)
      break
  x = x - 1

if x == 0:
  print("Not found\n")
```

> 30
>   29
>
> ---
>
> 50
>   50
>
> ---
>
> 1000000000
>   1200^2 + 31600^2
>   1000000000
>   (4ms)

Comment: Число находится в диапозоне от 1 до 10^9. По времени не пройдет

Comment: @user1337157 Для современных компьютеров перебрать `sqrt(10^9) = 10^4.5` чисел это вопрос в пределах одной двух секунд. Кроме того в аллгоритме как понимаю достаточно перебирать только одно из слогаемых, второе вычислять на основе первого. У этого ответа явно будет перебор двух вложенных циклов т.е. 10^9.

Comment: Ограничение по времени 2 секунды. В любом случае, перебор неэффективен. Спасибо за помощь, но я, к сожалению, так не понял в чем ошибка в моем алгоритме

Comment: Убрал второй цикл

Comment: @user1337157 Ваш вариант решения который в вопросе не подходящий, т.к. во первых он не самое ближайшее (максимальное) всегда находит, во вторых даёт только один ответ а может быть несколько ответов, мне кажется без перебора не обойтись.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что ваше решение принципиально отличается от моего? Добавить сбор всех вариантов - много ума не надо. Если вы посмотрите в код автора, в качестве ответа он выводит сумму, а не список сумм квадратов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот моё решение на Питоне, перебирает меньшее из двух чисел в отрезке `[1, sqrt(n)]` а второе вычисляет по формуле, находит все ответы для максимальной из найденных сумм, для максимального числа `10^9` отрабатывает алгоритм мгновенно.

Вот код на Питоне, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/@moytrage/RuStackOverflow744343):

```
n = 1000000000
sqrt_n = int(n ** 0.5)
max_sum = 0
result = []

for i in range(1, sqrt_n + 1):
    j = int((n - i * i) ** 0.5)
    if j < i:
        break
    s = i * i + j * j
    if (s > max_sum):
        max_sum = s
        result = []        
    if (s == max_sum):
        result.append((i, j))

print(max_sum, result)
```

Вот какой вывод для примера 10^9:

```
1000000000 [(1200, 31600), (7696, 30672), (10000, 30000), (18000, 26000), (19920, 24560)]
```